# Interact and re-organize JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have receive data from endpoint which is not good enough to be displayed in table until some changes are made. Here is how I receive example data:

```
const data = [
    {
      Year: 2017,
      OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0,
      DefaultPrincipalInt: 749.0,
      OriginalPrincipal: 127850.0
    },
    {
      Year: 2018,
      OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0,
      DefaultPrincipalInt: 1543.0,
      OriginalPrincipal: 182566.0
    },
    {
      Year: 2019,
      OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0,
      DefaultPrincipalInt: 30.0,
      OriginalPrincipal: 108000.0
    }
  ];
```

But the data should be grouped by all of these repeating properties except year. Here is how it should look like:

```
const dataDesired = [
  {
    item: "OriginalIntBalanceOverdue",
    "2017": 0.0,
    "2018": 0.0,
    "2019": 0.0
  },
  {
    item: "DefaultPrincipalInt",
    "2017": 749.0,
    "2018": 1543.0,
    "2019": 200
  },
  {
    item: "OriginalPrincipal",
    "2017": 127850.0,
    "2018": 30.0,
    "2019": 108000.0
  }
];
```

I added codesandbox to make it more easy for implementing solutions:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-jones-sgy4u?file=/src/App.js:697-1016

I tried several ways with

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{
....
...
}
```

But I was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out. Here I am assuming that you have always the `Year` field exists.

```js
const data = [{ Year: 2017, OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0, DefaultPrincipalInt: 749.0, OriginalPrincipal: 127850.0}, { Year: 2018, OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0, DefaultPrincipalInt: 1543.0, OriginalPrincipal: 182566.0}, { Year: 2019, OriginalIntBalanceOverdue: 0.0, DefaultPrincipalInt: 30.0, OriginalPrincipal: 108000.0}];

const res = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  let year = null;
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === 'Year') year = value;
    else {
      if (res[key] === undefined) {
        res[key] = {}; res[key].item = key;
      }
      res[key][year] = value;
    }
  });
});

const result = Object.values(res);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: I was looking for more automatic code because response object  properties for each year in response are way more - about 50. That's why I prefer not to declare const 'res' and adding properties 1 by 1.

Comment: @BorislavStefanov I've updated my answer. You can try thiss.

Comment: This is working just as expected. Thank you